# Why doesn't Stack Overflow automatically recommend labels or tags?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags

We must add tags by ourselves. Why doesn't Stack Overflow automatically recommend labels or tags?

Comment: It's difficult to do and will result in many incorrectly tagged questions.

Comment: Just mark all questions c# and Jon Skeet can answer them all.

Answer (score 11):

You're the one asking the question.  It's a lot easier for you to just say what it's about than for a piece of software to try and figure it out.

Comment: I just want to ask and discuss whether it's a feature QA platform should offer.